# How to find derivative of this integral?

Tags: partial-derivative

I need to find the partial derivative

$\frac{\partial}{\partial t} \int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-a\tau}I(x,t-\tau)\ d\tau$.

The answer is given by

$I(x,t)-a\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-a\tau}I(x,t-\tau)\ d\tau$.

What rule should I use to get the above answer?

Comment: It is just a variable stands for infected cells concentration.

Comment: Your comment does not say what the meaning of $I(x,t)$ is.

Comment: It represents the concentration of cells which depends on space and time.

Comment: @Fatimah We got that. That doesn't tell us any of its mathematical properties. Does it, for instance, have a functional expression? Or does it fulfill a certain differential equation? Or anything else like that?

Comment: Yes it fulfills a certain delay partial differential equation within a system with distributed delay.

Comment: Well, then maybe that is essential to solving your problem. I suggest you include it in your post.

Comment: No sir the solution doesn’t depend on the equation of $I$. It can be done by inserting the partial derivative inside the integral, using the fact that $\frac{\partial}{\partial t}=-\frac{\partial}{\partial \tau}$, and finally using integration by parts. I have just realized the answer. Thanks for you all.